# Meteor: how to update DOM via Javascript without a page refresh?

Tags: dom, raphael, meteor

UPDATE:

It looks like [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274679/invoke-a-client-js-function-in-meteor-after-getting-results-from-the-server) may be the catalyst I'm looking for. Will test it and answer/close this question if so.

---

I'm sure I'll find the answer to this eventually, but I'm putting it out there now, in case someone else knows it right off...

I am using RaphaelJS to manipulate the DOM (adds a bunch of `SVG` tags to an identified `DIV`), and I want to re-render those specific DOM parts, if there's an update to the MongoDB collection.

As an example:
-Let's say that I have a collection called `PiePieces`.
-When the page is first rendered/ called, let's pretend that the number of pieces in the collection is 4.
-I programmatically add a pie piece using console: `PiePieces.insert({...})`
-I want the page to update like it would for a standard handlebars binding situation, but the problem is, the new entry needs to go through the Raphael script, which performs direct DOM manipulation.

So, the logic would go something like this:

MongoDB collection update event -> Client function call to manipulate DOM  -> DOM modified/ page updated without a refresh.

I've tried implementing this by reading values from the DOM itself, and I can get the updated DOM, but the entire page refreshes and/or I have to manually refresh the page, OR the DOM tree isn't completed yet, and so it's blank until I refresh.

Can you point me in the right direction, maybe with a small code snippet/example?
(if something similar already exists, just tell me where and I'll go digging)

Thanks in advance! (I am LOVING Meteor so far...)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want the [observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) method. You can assign callbacks to what you called "MongoDB collection update event" and thereafter call your DOM manipulating function that uses Raphaël or whatever.

It will look like this:

```
PiePieces.find().observe({
    changed: function(piePiece) {
        //call DOM manipulating function
    }
})
```

This will attach the callback to all PiePieces. If you don't want to attach the callback to all documents, query the ones you want on the find before the observe.

Answer (score 0):

you could reference the draw method from inside the template like so:

template.html

```
<template name="drawing">
  {{#each PiePieces}}
     {{draw piece}} <!-- assuming 'piece' is a property on 'PiePiece' -->
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

client.js

```
Template.drawing.PiePieces = function(){
  PiePieces.find();
}

Template.drawing.draw = function(piece){
  // your drawing method here
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going, and that makes sense... A couple of questions if I may: 1) the draw function/method would be DOM manipulation - meaning the entire InnerHTML of a named DIV would be altered. Would that still work?  2) I would like for the update to happen automatically (like an .autosubscribe) when the records in MongoDB change -- how exactly would I go about doing that in the client.js? .render? .defer? -- Not 100% on that part yet.

Comment: Mostly you should just fiddle with it and see what happens. To answer your questions 1) i believe the method is only going to run once for each piece and doesn't clear the template each time. 2) the update should happen automatically with the code i posted. Autosubscribe is for when you want a reactive function thats not necessarily tied to a mongo collection, like setting a property on Session.