# Meteor how to invoke client js function for only item added to Collection

Tags: meteor

With Meteor, I want new items that are added to a list to fade in.  However, I don't want every element in the list to fade in slowly when something is added, only the new element that is added.

I have the following Collection published by the server and subscribed on the client

```
List = new Meteor.Collection("List");


Meteor.autosubscribe(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe('list'); 
});
```

I have the following template:

```
<template name="list">
  {{#each list}}
    {{> list_item }}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name"list_item">
  {{ text }}
</template>
```

I would like to call the following when a new element is inserted into a Collection:

```
function (item) {
  var sel = '#' + item._id;
  Meteor.defer(function () {
    $(sel).fadeIn();
  });
}
```

I have tried using

```
List.find().observe({
  added: function (list_item) {
    var sel = '#' + list_item._id;
    Meteor.defer(function() {
      $(sel).fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

However, the function is called for **each** item in the list when a new list_item is added, rather than only for the single new item.

Comment: I have seen this that suggested observe: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274679/invoke-a-client-js-function-in-meteor-after-getting-results-from-the-server

I've also seen this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109788/callback-after-the-dom-was-updated-in-meteor-js

However, with both methods, all elements are faded in, instead of only the last inserted element.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: No, although I haven't tried in months...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you're supposed to call Meteor.defer directly, I couldn't find it in the docs. Also, the meteor versions of setTimeout and setInterval don't seem to be working properly and defer is just a wrapper around `Meteor.setTimeout(fn(), 0)` Anyway I got what I think you want working:

html:

```
<body>
  {{> list_items}}
</body>

<template name="list_items">
  <ul>
    {{#each list_items}}
      <li id="list-item-{{_id}}" style="display:none;">
        {{text}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

js:

```
List = new Meteor.Collection("List")

if (Meteor.is_client) {
  Meteor.subscribe("List")

  Meteor.autosubscribe(function(){
    List.find().observe({
      added: function(item){
        setTimeout("$('#list-item-"+item._id+"').fadeIn('slow')",10)
      }
    });
  });

  Template.list_items.list_items = function(){
    return List.find()
  }
}
```