# How to invoke a client side method from the server in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

The reverse (calling server-side from the client) is easily done with a Meteor Method.

Say that you want to run a client-side method from the server, either directly or as a callback. An example could be that a user signs up on your site. After the sign-up on the server is successful, a modal window pops up alerting them that the sign up has been successful (we're trying to go for a single page app feel, so not doing a router re-direct).

Previous searches seem to say that I need to create a reactive collection and monitor it with `observe()` just for this purpose:

[Invoke a client js function in Meteor after getting results from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274679/invoke-a-client-js-function-in-meteor-after-getting-results-from-the-server)

This seems kind of hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This should be helpful : http://code.subhog.com/client-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example, invoking `Accounts.createUser` [(docs)](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser) on the client would be a fine way to sign up a user and invoke a callback on success or error.

In general, you want client code to be conditional on data rather than on a particular server's state (you may one day have dozens of servers serving the same app!).

To run code on the client once if and when your data has a certain truth (e.g. `Meteor.userId()` is not `null`, so a user has logged in), you can use a `Deps.autorun` that `stop()`s itself [(docs)](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun).