# How to call Meteor client methods from server?

Tags: meteor

We can define methods on Meteor server and call them from clients, is there any way to call client defined methods from server?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905913/how-to-invoke-a-client-side-method-from-the-server-in-meteor

Answer (score 2):

As per official [Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/methods_header) there is no direct way to call client side methods from server but you can achieve that by using a smart package called [anti:methods](https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-methods)

1. You need to set the clientId which will be used to communicate to this particular client.

   ```js
   Tracker.autorun(function() {
      Meteor.ClientCall.setClientId(Meteor.userId());
   });
   ```
2. Defining a method

   ```js
   Meteor.ClientCall.methods({
     'chatMessage': function(username, message) {
       ...
     },
   });
   ```
3. Calling a method

   ```js
   Meteor.ClientCall.apply(clientId, method, arguments, callback)
   ```

Note: This package is not fully functional. Check the [readme](https://github.com/anticoders/meteor-methods/blob/master/README.md) for more information.

Alternatively if you just want to re-use some code in both server and client, you can create a global function in common folder and call it from anywhere you want. Just make sure it does not contain any browser specific code and it loads before the function where you calling it.